# 'NA' value lost after using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transfer the data from origin_csv file to a destiny_csv file using first the `read_csv` and later `to_csv` functions.

The problem is that my origin_csv file already has 'NA' in the missing values cells, and when I complete the process, the destiny_csv file has the 'NA' replaced by empty spaces. I really want to keep 'NA' in those cells.

How can I keep the 'NA's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is `na_rep`

```
DataFrame.to_csv('destiny_csv' , na_rep='NA')
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, when you read in the file you can prevent pandas from converting those 'NA' values to NaNs by setting keep_default_na to False.  Then, when you save using to_csv, the 'NA' values should be there.

```
df = pd.read_csv("origin_csv", keep_default_na=False)
```